# Naming collision between attribute 'category' and association 'category' on model products

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is the products model, the line of the problem is the association for products and categories:    products.belongsTo(models.category)

```
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class products extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      products.belongsTo(models.category)//a category can belong to many products
      products.belongsToMany(models.orders, {
        through: "orderproducts", //join table name here
        foreignKey: "productId"
      })

    }
  };
  products.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    price: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    category: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'products',
  });
  return products;
};
```